# error message in qt designer in Linux

Tags: linux, qt, cross-platform

while running an application written in windows on linux, i encountered a problem-

i can't edit the cpp file of widget. all the other classes are editable.

The error message appears on the top of the screen and looks like that:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just a guess, but the file might have been saved with e.g. Windows cp1252 encoding (or something else) and now you need to specify the same encoding to load it on Linux.

What happens when you click on the "Select Encoding" button?

EDIT:
The encoding might be something like UTF-16-le or UCS-2 or win1252, but that's just a guess.  If you can't guess the encoding, you could try using some software to try to figure it out.  There are various tools or libraries to do this, written in various languages:

http://freshmeat.net/projects/enca/
https://metacpan.org/pod/Encode::Detect
https://metacpan.org/pod/Encode::Guess

Comment: many encoding possibilities appear. how can I know how my file was saved?

Comment: I'm working on both Linux and Windows. When I check the properties of the encoding in QT Windows it says System. how can i check on the windows computer what is the system encoding? thank u for your time!

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't know.  But can you specify e.g. utf-8 for the encoding on Windows?